# Should I use arrary or sqlite database?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

I'm seeking assistance on a APP I need to create. I don't have no experience with android app development but, I'm studying and practicing.

I'm trying to build an app to record payments from a list of customers and print a receipt when paid. I download a list of customers with pending balance, using json array into android. Now, I'm confused, don't know if I should use arrays or a database to store the list, since I need to update (upload) later to the server. SQLite seems like an option but, I have to download the list every time user is connected to WiFi.

I guess I have to store the payments on an array and flush it once uploaded.

Can you please tell me what would be the best option for the tasks I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you have to store and retrieve values, then a database is what you want. Arrays are fixed - unless you don't implement a way to serialize them to a file. Moreover, arrays are only usable for a few items (say 100 items). A database table can hold several fields, to give you more details. And it is searchable, sortable, you can use aggregation functions and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your use case.  Arrays and sqlite can work independently or together.

If you are going to upload the data instantly after downloading within the same session, then you can keep it in the Array and upload it after what ever you need to do with it.  Keep in mind that Arrays will be kept in memory and depending on where you are keeping the array object, they might not persist through the life cycle of an activity or the life cycle of your application.

SQLite on the hand writes data to disk, so you will be able to persist it even after user has backed out of your application.

> ...since I need to update (upload) later to the server

Based on the above, it seems like you should persist your data on disk.  SQLite is one of the options for persisting data.  Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to see what else is available for persisting data.

You can load up any persisted data into your array and upload it after you have processed it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Once is uploaded to  server, the local sqlite database needs to be updated or recreated with the new info again.

Comment: The data downloaded would be used temporarily until payments are uploaded. Once uploaded, I guess I need to delete the DB and save with the new info. Don't know if that is the best way to do it but, it sounds like it.

Comment: You can just update the data in current data base and replace it with new data.

Comment: Thanks all for replying. Just created a DB with two tables, once everything gets uploaded to server, both tables get zapped, then download the new info. I need to download it again because user would not know if other records got updated while on the road.